# Filtrar JSON Angular

Tags: json, angularjs, http

Buenas estoy haciendo una aplicación en angular a la cual hago un get http para cargar un json pero queria saber como filtrar para recoger solo lo que quiera,

Esto es mi provider y la ruta donde cargo el json

```
 objetos: string = '../assets/recursos/objetos.json';

 loadobjetos() {
    return this.http
      .get(this.objetos)
      .toPromise();
  }
```

Y este es mi home.ts:

```
cargarChampions() {
    this.http.loadobjetos().then(
      (res) => {
        this.objetos= res['objetos'];
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    )
  }
```

Este es el formato del json

```
{
 "objetos":[
  {
   "name":"1" ,
   "image":""
  },
  {
   "name":"2" ,
   "image":""
  }
]
}
```

Como tendría que cambiar el home.ts o mi provider para solo coger el name 2 y su imagen sin tener que cargar todo el json.

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que tu carga de datos es un Json fijo, entonces el filtrado lo tienes que realizar el filtrado al tener los datos cargados.

```
cargarChampions() {
    this.http.loadobjetos().then(
      (res) => {
        this.objetos= res["objetos"].filter( (e)=> e.name === '2' );
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    )
  }
```

```js
var res ={
   "objetos":[
    {
     "name":"1" ,
     "image":""
    },
    {
     "name":"2" ,
     "image":""
    }
  ]
}

var objetos2 = res["objetos"].filter( (e) => e.name==='2');
console.log(objetos2)
```